# Getting string index of bound error

Tags: java, algorithm

> Given a string that contains a single pair of parenthesis, compute
>   recursively a new string made of only of the parenthesis and their
>   contents, so "xyz(abc)123" yields "(abc)". parenBit("xyz(abc)123") →
>   "(abc)"
>
> parenBit("x(hello)") → "(hello)"
>
> parenBit("(xy)1") → "(xy)"

```
 boolean foundc = false;
    boolean foundd = false;

    public String parenBit(String str) {
        char c = str.charAt(0);
        char d = str.charAt(str.length() - 1);


        if(c == '('){
            foundc = true;
            return parenBit(str.substring(0, str.length() - 1));

        }

        if(foundc == false){
            return parenBit(str.substring(1, str.length() - 1));

        }

        if(d == ')'){
            foundd = true;
            str.substring(0, str.length() - 1);

        }

        if(foundd == false){
            return str.substring(0, str.length() - 2);

        }


        return  "";
    }
```

Why does this return a "String index out of range: 0" error?

Comment: Which line gives you the error? Have you stepped through this with a debugger?

Comment: can you please post the full stacktrace?

Comment: Why don't you get the position of the `(` char and the `)` char, then return what's between them? Looks strange how you are trying to do it

Comment: what if str is "". char d = str.charAt(str.length() - 1); str,length = 0, so you would be trying to access charAt(-1) -> error

Answer (score 0):

With each recursion you are reducing the length of the string that you check. In the last recursion you will have an empty string and try to access index 0. Add a check on top of the function if the string is empty and if it is, break.

You should also check for length being 2 before calling `str.substring(1, str.length() - 1)` or you might get another index error.

Answer (score 0):

You're probably better off just using Regular Expressions. Something like this:

```
var input = "xyz(abc)123(blah)";
var exp = @"\((?<content>[^)]*)\)";
var matches = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Matches(input, exp);

foreach (var match in matches) {
    // Gets called twice, once for "abc" and once for "blah"
    var group = match.Groups["content"].Value;
}
```